# Pass Multiple files to function

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have a function deals with xml files after determine it by OpenFileDialog and it supports multi selection of files

```
                    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
                    openFileDialog1.Filter = "*.xml|*.XML";
                    openFileDialog1.Title="Please Select Xml file to convert ";
                    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                        {
                           //string lsit contain file names
                            Filestoconvert.Add(file);
                        }
                    }
```

and the function make process on it.

```
               for (int i = 0; i < Filestoconvert.Count; i++)
                {
                    XmlProcess( Filestoconvert[i]);
                }
```

but when select files only last selected file pass to the function and other files just read in the list only.
I want to select multiple files and pass it to this function to process these files one by one without passing files manually to it.

Can any one explain how to do that ? Give me piece of code or link?

Comment: Why do you do `openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + file`? `file` already contains the path.

Comment: > but when select files only last selected file pass to the function and other files just read in the list only.

what do you mean by that? Is the content of `Filestoconvert` not what it should be or is the XmlProcess method not working as expected?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler XmlProcess method not working as expected

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov you are right i remove this , but the problem still exist

Comment: I don't think your problem is in the code you've included in the question.

Comment: @user3602366 So what behavior is expected?

Comment: XmlProcess  work correctly i tested it more than 10 times with different input the problem only pass last file in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the implementation of `XmlProcess` it is a guessing game. You say that this method doesn't work as expected, yet you don't show us how this method works. How can you expect anyone to help you?

Nonetheless, if you want to pass multiple files to the function, just change the signature from

```
void XmlProcess(string file) // should be something very similar
```

to

```
void XmlProcess(IEnumerable files)
```

Now you can pass an array, a list or any other object implementing the `IEnumerable` interface.